# Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@type' that is to contain type id

Tags: java, json, serialization, java-8, jackson

I am trying to write code that uses `Jackson` to serialize/deserialize the objects to/from `File`.

The objects are Polymorphic in nature.  My interface looks like

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(RemoteDataSource.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(FileDataSource.class)
})
public interface DataSource {
}
```

and the implementations as

```
public class FileDataSource implements DataSource {
    private String path;
    private String delimiter;
    private String fileNamePattern;

    @JsonCreator
    public FileDataSource(@JsonProperty("path") String path,
                          @JsonProperty("delimiter") String delimiter,
                          @JsonProperty("fileNamePattern") String fileNamePattern) {
        this.path = path;
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.fileNamePattern = fileNamePattern;
    }
 ...
}
```

and

```
public class RemoteDataSource implements DataSource {
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    @JsonCreator
    public RemoteDataSource(@JsonProperty("host") String host,
                            @JsonProperty("port") int port,
                            @JsonProperty("userName") String userName,
                            @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

   ...
}
```

and in `WorkflowConfig` use them

```
public class WorkflowConfig {
    private String name;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @JsonCreator
    public WorkflowConfig(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                          @JsonProperty("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
  ...
}
```

and then I write my test which looks like

```
 @Test
    public void testSerializeAndSerializeFileDataSourceFromFile() throws Exception {
        File fileDataSource = temporaryFolder.newFile("fileDataSource.json");

        DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource("/tmp/", ",", ".*");
        WorkflowConfig config = new WorkflowConfig("fileWorkflowConfig", dataSource);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(fileDataSource, config);

        assertTrue(fileDataSource.length() > 0);

        DataSource readDataSource = mapper.readValue(fileDataSource, DataSource.class);
        assertNotNull(readDataSource);
    }
```

and it fails as

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@type' that is to contain type id  (for class com.datasources.DataSource)
 at [Source: /var/folders/g3/wtbqfj7d5fsbkz1gm74kqy380000gn/T/junit5577276768876379004/fileDataSource.json; line: 1, column: 123]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1340)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1196)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedUsingDefaultImpl(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2731)
    at com.workflow.WorkflowConfigTest.testSerializeAndSerializeFileDataSourceFromFile(WorkflowConfigTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

When serialized, the data on file looks like

```
{"name":"fileWorkflowConfig","dataSource":{"@type":"FileDataSource","path":"/tmp/","delimiter":",","fileNamePattern":".*"}}
```

I believe `Jackson` needs the `@type` information to construct the right object back.

But from application perspective I do not need the information, so I used

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

However I am believe I am making mistake, what can I do now?

The complete codebase is on [GitHub](https://github.com/101bits/jackson-serialize-polymorphic-objects). you can see the failing test there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test has a mistake, you are serializing WorkflowConfig but trying to deserialize directly DataSource.

The test deserialize should be:

```
        WorkflowConfig workflowConfig= mapper.readValue(fileDataSource, WorkflowConfig.class);
        assertNotNull(workflowConfig);
        assertNotNull(workflowConfig.getDataSource());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was the issue